# AngularJS Isolate scope not being passed to directive

Tags: angularjs

I have been scratching my head on this particular test for hours. I believe that the demonstrated directive should be working, yet I am getting undefined for the value being passed to the isolate scope.

Code:

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
    <a ng-href="#" class="test-scope" name="test">Console should say 'test' but gives undefined</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('testScope', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            scope: {
                name: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.name);
            }
        };
    });
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jPtb3/8/

Any help would be appreciated, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: changed your Fiddle, see under

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `=` to `@`

```
angular.module('components', [])
.directive('testScope', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
       scope: {
            name: "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.name);
        }
    };
})

angular.module('myApp', ['components']);
```

See fixed <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPtb3/9/)</kbd>

`@` – binds the value of parent scope property (which always a string) to the local scope.

`=` – binds parent scope property directly which will be evaluated before being passed in.

Comment: see this link: http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/. You can find examples and description

Answer (score 1):

You are interpreting the isolated scope constructs incorrectly.

When you say `name=` you are saying that there is attribute on the directive declaration html which is of same name `name` and whatever the attribute value is present, bind to that property name in the scope.

In this case there should be a scope property name `test` on the scope where directive is declared. The `name` property on the directive scope would point to this test property on parent (not literally)

Bottom line your directive scope `name` -> container scope `test` property.

See my plunker here http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/ANzUf/

Comment: I don't understand. My a tag has an attribute of name="test" -- Is this not what you are telling me to do?

Comment: @francisco.preller i have added a fiddle. See what i am saying in action here http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/ANzUf/

Comment: I see, and it makes sense now. Thanks for the info!